# No show customers in Customers section table

Tags: magento2, customer, backend, magento-upgrade, table

I have a problem after upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4.
After correctly upgrate I don't see customers inside the table customers.
In particular, I'm seeing only the first row on the table while all other rows are empty.
If I select any row I note that the javascritp correcty load that customer.

I attach an image to explain as better as possible...

[image]

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, Please do reindexing. Please use the below commands to do full indexing.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Please let me know if still not fixed.